# the value of the field FileArrayAdapter.c is not used

Tags: android, field

hello guys i am new at this. I am trying to create a simple file chooser and i hit a bump
this is my problem

```
private Context c;
private int id;
private List<Option>items;

public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Option> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    c = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    items = objects;
}

}
```

it says:

```
the value of the field FileArrayAdapter.c is not used
the value of the field FileArrayAdapter.id is not used
the value of the field FileArrayAdapter.items is not used
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning that indicates you are never accessing the `c`, `id`, and `items` fields in your object. Your app should still compile and run just fine. It's nothing to worry about if you plan on using those fields at some point. If not, why do they exist in the first place?

Comment: Hi again!
I was trying to make a simple file chooser and it worked.
now i tried to attach it to my main app.. its my project at school to make one. i chose to make a video editor. when i attached the file chooser and ran it, an error occurred
I could open the app but cannot open the file chooser. and then something went wrong. i couldn't run my app anymore.
I tried looking at the devices i have made but it was missing.
can you guys help me out? thank you so much.

Comment: Ask this as another question on StackOverflow. Be specific about your problem and include the relevant portion of your logcat. A video editor is a very ambitious undertaking for a school project. I would suggest trying something a bit more manageable for your first Android app.

Comment: i agree. it is very ambitious.. but it is only a simple one. i only like to cut and merge videos ... also im new here..
when i ask another question, it says "this question body does not meet our quality standards"
what do i do with that? im really sorry about this